# Origen de "ser un calavera"

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa

¿Por qué se dice que alguien es un `calavera` para expresar que anda siempre flirteando con mujeres?

El DRAE recoge

> [Calavera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6iNtWmT)
>
> 5. m. Hombre disipado, juerguista e irresponsable. U. t. c. adj.

Buscando la [etimología de calavera](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?calavera) (aparte de la referencia al cráneo) solo he podido encontrar que es debido a que a estas personas trasnochadoras "la vida las adelgaza, y su rostro se vuelve pálido, semejante a una calavera" que no me parece una explicación muy fiable.

¿Sabe alguien cuál es el origen de la expresión "ser un calavera" para designar a un hombre mujeriego y/o juerguista?

Comment: Coloqué la etiqueta "España" porque por aquí no tiene el significado de la pregunta. Al menos en Colombia la usamos con el significado de la RAE que no tiene nada que ver con **coquetear** (palabra original del español que prefiero al anglicismo) sino más bien con lo de "irresponsable" y algo antisocial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues revisando la historia de la palabra a través de los diccionarios parece que la evolución ha sido la siguiente:

En 1729, el primer diccionario de la RAE, el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, refleja para *calavera* únicamente el significado óseo. Ya hemos discutido aquí en otras ocasiones el carácter poco científico y muy literario del diccionario por aquel entonces, y este es uno de esos casos en los que merece la pena pararse a leer la definición:

> CALAVERA. f.f. La cabéza del hombre, ù de otro qualquiera animál, yá despojada por la muerte de todo el adorno exterior é interior de facciones, y sentidos, y que solamente le ha quedado la armazón de los huessos, en que se contempla una horrorosa figura de lo que fue.

Ni rastro de la acepción que comentas, aunque resulta curioso también leer el significado de esta otra palabra muy cercana (gracias, Rodrigo):

> CALAVEREAR. v. a. de que usó Quevedo para dar a entender, que las hermosúras y las mozas con la mala vida y los vícios se pierden, y se ponen presto en punto de dar fin, y ser calaveras muriéndose.

Vemos ya pues un indicio de que la mala vida te puede llevar a la tumba y sacar tu calavera, expresión inventada al parecer por Francisco de Quevedo. De ahí seguramente surgió en la siguiente versión del diccionario, de 1780, lo siguiente:

> CALAVERA. Apodo que se da á la persona de poco juicio, y así se dice: es un CALAVERA.

Se continúa pues la metáfora de que las acciones de un hombre de poco juicio le pueden llevar con facilidad a la tumba y convertirse, por tanto, en una calavera pero de verdad. De hecho, este diccionario actualiza los términos *calaverear* ("hacer calaveradas"), y *calaverada* ("acción desconcertante de hombre de poco juicio"). Al menos ya no se restringe el significado a las mujeres.

Esta acepción se mantuvo a lo largo de los años (en la forma de "hombre de poco juicio y asiento") hasta su versión de 2001 incluida. Por otro lado, desde 1984 existe otra acepción:

> **calavera.** fig. Hombre dado al libertinaje.

Acepción que también se mantuvo hasta 2001. En la última versión del diccionario, la de 2014, estas dos acepciones se fusionaron en una, la que has comentado en el texto de la pregunta.

Se ve que poco a poco el término *calavera* pasó de denominar al "hombre de poco juicio" a denominar además al "hombre irresponsable" y de ahí al "dado al libertinaje" (irresponsable y sin preocupaciones). Esta evolución es la que ha dado lugar a la acepción actual.

El primer caso que he encontrado en el CORDE (del sustantivo "calavera") es el siguiente:

> *Os aseguro de veras
>
>   que no hago memoria ni
>
>   del nombre, ni de las señas.
>
>   Don Luis María... ¡Ya caigo!
>
>   Justamente, un calavera,
>
>   como otros muchos, que allí
>
>   hubo entre gentes diversas.*
>
> Ramón de la Cruz, "Los picos de oro", 1765 (España).

El cual coincide en fechas con la primera aparición de la definición en un diccionario de la RAE en 1780. El registro de Quevedo del verbo *calaverear* con el significado mencionado arriba está fechado entre 1597 y 1645.

Comment: ¡Genial! Una consulta, por curiosidad: para estas respuestas, ¿entras una a una en todas las ediciones del NTLLE?

Comment: @fedorqui por supuesto. :-)

Comment: @fedorqui bueno, en realidad no. Lo que hago es mirar las primeras definiciones. Entre los años 1780 y 1803 las definiciones se suelen estabilizar, y luego lo que hago es una búsqueda dicotómica. Si tengo que buscar una variación de una definición entre 1800 y 2000, miro la de 1899 y veo si ha cambiado. Si es así, busco hacia 1850. Que no, busco en 1950. Es la mejor forma de ir localizando los cambios en las definiciones. Además, lo normal es que restrinja la búsqueda a los diccionarios de la RAE, solo ocasionalmente busco en otros.

Comment: ¡Ajá! También uso la búsqueda dicotómica cuando uso el NTLLE :) En lo que dudo es en utilizar o no todos los recursos. Por ejemplo para _calavera_ veo obras como _1901 TORO Y GÓMEZ_ o _1852 CASTRO Y ROSSI (A-COSTRA)_. ¿Las consideras también?

Comment: @fedorqui pues si veo que con los diccionarios de la RAE me basta para formular una respuesta, no los considero. Pero a veces pasa que no son suficientes, o no tienen la respuesta que busco, y entonces tiro de los demás, como me ha pasado en respuestas recientes a otras preguntas. Es cierto que a veces en otros diccionarios se encuentran datos muy curiosos que pueden ayudar bastante según la pregunta.

Comment: Te sugiero agregar la entrada de "Calaverear" del diccionario de 1729: _v.a. de que usó Quevedo para dar a entender, que las hermosuras y las mozas con la mala vida y los vicios se pierden, y se ponen presto en punto de dar fin, y ser calaveras muriéndose. Lat. Nimium depravari, vitiari._ (O sea, "corromper", "viciar").

Answer (score 1):

Estoy leyendo MANUAL DE ZONCERAS ARGENTINAS de Jauretche. El autor cuenta una anécdota en la que Bernardo de Irigoyen tiene que ir a la cárcel y ver en qué estado se encuentra José Mármol.  Se sorprende al ver que está jugando ajedrez con el comisario, quién le dice :” dígale a don Fermín que Mármol está conmigo de calavera, pues se ha metido en amoríos  con una dama y los parientes lo buscan con malas intenciones."
En este sentido, creo que se ajusta muy bien le definición de"mujeriego, libertino"...no?

Answer (score 0):

A ver, yo no he consultado nada, pero, usando sólo la intuición y el sentido común, se llega a la conclusión de que un calavera es alguien que se ríe de todo (las calaveras tienen sonrisa eterna) y no se toma nada en serio. El típico personaje que se pasa la vida de fiesta, derrocha todo el dinero que pasa por sus manos, no paga sus deudas, deja enfangados a quienes le avalan, etc. En definitiva, alguien en quien no puedes confiar y que, de seguro, si montas un negocio con él te va a dejar empantanado.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Yo asocio calavera con pirata, ya que está era la insignia de sus banderas. Entonces ser un pirata también implica la irresponsabilidad, el desapego, esa cierta bruteza y siempre se lo asoció con mujeriego.